# Installing PHP 5.3 on a Windows host with both Apache and IIS

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, php

I'm currently experimenting with a couple of configurations of Apache and IIS on the same server box - so far using Apache as a proxy for IIS is winning, but another of my setups has Apache on a non-standard port with IIS taking the majority of traffic.

Both of these machines currently have PHP 5.2 installed. I want to upgrade to PHP 5.3, but the installer asks which server I'm running - I'm running both - so what do I tell it?

Which configuration will be the most flexible, tell it we're running IIS, or tell it we're running Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I give up.

I'm gonna install PHP twice, once for Apache, once for IIS.

The IIS / PHP traffic is slow low, it's not gonna give much overhead anyways.

Comment: I had a really troublesome time getting PHP to work with IIS. Eventually I got it going as a FastCGI service: http://superuser.com/questions/115685/php-5-3-1-with-iis-6-0-returning-404-but-file-is-really-there - either way, if you install for IIS first it should be trivial to get it working for Apache (perhaps in fastcgi mode too)